# Can't sign in with Apple on the independent watchOS app

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, sign-in-with-apple

I try to implement authentication with Sign In with Apple on watchOS app without iPhone.

```
import AuthenticationServices

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInBtn: WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton!

    @IBAction func signInWithAppleTapped() {
      let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
      let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
      request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]

      let authController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
      authController.delegate = self
      authController.performRequests()
}
```

After tap on *sign in* button on simulator I see this:

> Create Passcode to Continue 
>   Create a passcode for this Apple Watch to sign in to apps using you Apple ID.

Passcode is added in settings. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a requirement of Apple Watch users that their device has a passcode in order to use sign in with Apple. Running your app with your own Apple Watch set as the scheme should allow you to test it. If you don't have a passcode on your physical device, you can set one in the Settings app in watchOS.

Comment: What steps should be done in simulator? I added passcode but problem remains

Comment: I was unable to set one in the simulator, so I assume it’s a bug with the simulator. Are you certain it’s set? Do you have your own Apple Watch?

Comment: Unfortunately my watch can’t update to watchos 6, so I don’t have option to test on real device right now

Comment: Sorry to hear. I've made two submissions in Feedback Assistant, one that the Apple Watch simulator won't set passcodes (FB7619473) and that the Apple Watch simulator shouldn't require a passcode when testing sign in with Apple (FB7619478). If you duplicate the submissions and they will rise on Apple's priority list.

If you want, I'd be happy to test your app through TestFlight since my watch runs watchOS 6.